# Testing a chance-based class

Tags: ruby, random, statistics, rspec

So, chance, huh? Randomness.

I'm looking into how I can test a class whose sole responsibility is to return weighted random results, that is, where there is a set probability of returning true.

The trouble is, random being what it is, sometimes the result doesn't reflect the initial probability.

Here's my attempt, which passes the specs *most* of the time.

chance.rb

```
class Chance

  include Singleton

  def self.percent(amount)
    (rand(100) + 1) <= amount
  end

  # x in y chance of being true
  def self.proportion(x, y)
    rand(y) <= x
  end

end
```

chance_spec.rb

```
describe Chance do

  context 'percent' do

    it 'should return true 50% of the time' do
      results = 100.times.collect{ Chance.percent(50) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should be_within(10).of(50)
    end

    it 'should return true 75% of the time' do
      results = 100.times.collect{ Chance.percent(75) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should be_within(10).of(75)
    end

    it 'should return true 25% of the time' do
      results = 100.times.collect{ Chance.percent(25) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should be_within(10).of(25)
    end

    it 'should return true 100% of the time' do
      results = 100.times.collect{ Chance.percent(100) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should eq(100)
    end

    it 'should return true 0% of the time' do
      results = 100.times.collect{ Chance.percent(0) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should eq(0)
    end

  end

  context 'proportion' do

    it 'should return true 6 in 12 times' do
      results = 12.times.collect{ Chance.proportion(6, 12) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should be_within(2).of(6)
    end

    it 'should return true 2 in 6 times' do
      results = 6.times.collect{ Chance.proportion(2, 6) }
      results.select{|x|x}.count.should be_within(1).of(2)
    end

  end

end
```

Any clues?

Comment: My first instinct would be to increase the test by 2 orders of magnitude to reduce random fluctuation (the more test the closer to real probability)

Comment: this will be a maximum likelihood estimation problem: this looks promising - http://petertessin.com/MaxLik.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on your current code:

- Your test case descriptions don't make a lot of sense - try reading them out loud: It should return true 50% of the time... and 75% of the time... and 25% of the time... etc.. Wait, which is it? You're omitting the argument in the description, so the descriptions become confusing and/or meaningless.
- You're adding 1 in the `percent` method, but not in the `proportion` method. So a zero-in-1 chance always works out to true! And even a 0 in 1,000,000 is still a chance! Probably not what you want. For both methods I'd suggest using a range argument instead.
- You're including `Singleton` for no reason, since you define your methods as class/static methods. So there's no point in instantiating the class - as a singleton or otherwise.
- What happens if you pass floating point or negative numbers? That's an exercise for the reader.
- Your `results.select{|x|x}.count` can be simplified to just `results.count(&:itself)`
- Let one method call the other: `percent` could just call `proportion(amount, 100)`. That way you can focus on testing `proportion` as that's the only one that actually doesn't anything random. And you'd more easily avoid/fix the bug mentioned above, since it'd only exist in one method, not two.

But as for testing randomness in general: In this case, I'd say don't bother. Because you can't really test it. Your current tests are fuzzy (±10 within target) just so they'll pass more reliably. But that's changing the tests to suit the output, rather than the other way around.

What you want are tests that are strictly pass/fail. This you can do for things like `it "raises an ArgumentError for negative arguments"` but not so much for the normal operation of the methods.

What it comes down to is whether you trust Ruby to:

- do basic arithmetic and comparison
- reliably generate pseudo random numbers ([here's the C source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/abae70d6ed63054d7d01bd6cd80c1b5b98b93ba3/random.c#L182) for Ruby's random, in case you're interested)

If you trust that, well, testing doesn't make much sense anymore.

Instead spend the time reviewing your code throughly. As seen above, your tests didn't cover the zero-in-N chance bug, and you didn't catch it either. For 2 single-line methods, you wrote an order of magnitude more test code - that effort seems misplaced, when the tests are fudged to pass *and* the code is buggy.

If you still insist on writing a test, then write a single test case that takes maybe a million samples for 50% or 1-in-2, and checks whether the result is within a narrower tolerance. But I'd run this test by itself a dozen times, but disable it when running the full suite (e.g. tag it so it can be included/excluded easily). It may still fail because *it is still random*, but that's no reason to fail the entire suite if you've tested thoroughly beforehand. (Edit: For a small project, it's fine to run this test every time, but if your code is on a CI server or you have automation relying on the result of the tests - e.g. can't commit/push to SCM without green tests - it's a pain to have all that at the mercy of randomness.)

Meanwhile you can still do single-sample tests for outliers: 0% chance should be false, 100% should be true, and 0-in-1 should be false, 1-in-1 should be true. Those can be run with the rest of the suite everytime - and should they suddenly, randomly fail, well, something's definitely wrong so start debugging.

Comment: Wow! I'd never seen the `itself` method before.

Comment: @AJFaraday It's a recent'ish addition (Ruby 2.x-something, I think). But it's a welcome one to be sure!

Comment: There is some math to use (I am not sure which) that will give tests that fail arbitrarly rarely (like 1 time in 10 million tries or even less) a test like that could be included in the test suit with no problem in my opinion

Comment: @Flambino Just incidentally,  I did find a solution, involving seeding the random. It's probably not ideal, but it is, at least, consistent.

Comment: @Caridorc it could. Really depends on how you use your tests. If you're just running them yourself, it's probably fine. But if a spurious failure causes all sorts of automated red flags on some CI server, it can be a hassle

Comment: @AJFaraday That's the problem: You want your method to be _random_ - not consistent. If you seed the random generator the same way each time your tests aren't testing how it would actually work. Again, tests don't do well with randomness - best you can do is sample _a lot_ and hope results fit a narrow tolerance

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is you are testing chance (pun intended). Don't test the chances. Test the logic behind the chances.

If you test chance, you are essentially writing unit tests for the `rand` function, which I'm sure has been tested thoroughly. You don't need to test this. You do want to test the logic in your class. As such, you need to make the random, unrandom. Composition and dependency injection is the solution here. The random number generator should be its own object, which you can mock in your tests. It also means your `Chance` class is no longer a singleton:

```ruby
class Chance

  def initialize(number_generator)
    @number_generator = number_generator
  end

  def percent(amount)
    (generate_number(100) + 1) <= amount
  end

  # x in y chance of being true
  def proportion(x, y)
    generate_number(y) <= x
  end

private

  def generate_number(seed)
    number_generator.generate seed
  end

end
```

Then you just need two sub classes. The first is the "real" class used in your application:

```ruby
class RandomNumberGenerator
  def generate(seed)
    rand(seed)
  end
end
```

The other is a test stub:

```ruby
class TestRandomNumberGenerator
  def generate(seed)
    raise 'This method should be stubbed in your tests'
  end
end
```

And some code constructing the Chance objects:

```ruby
real_chance = Chance.new(RandomNumberGenerator.new)
test_chance = Chance.new(TestRandomNumberGenerator.new)
```

Since the `generate_number` method exists, you should be able to mock calls to it, even if it is private:

```ruby
real_chance.should_receive(:generate_number).with(3).and_return(80)
```

Then you don't need the number generator objects and the Chance#generate_number method becomes:

```ruby
def generate_number(seed)
  rand(seed)
end
```